# How to plot date-time and value_counts() of non numerical data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

I have the following column for `connect_start`

```
0   2019-01-01 00:01:44
1   2019-01-01 00:02:57
2   2019-01-01 00:24:09
3   2019-01-01 01:35:23
4   2019-01-01 01:46:41
```

And a column of `advertisement_id` which the customer watched to get access to internet 
example:

```
0 1
1 2 
2 3
3 2
4 1
```

How do I plot both of these column to see `value_counts()` of `advertisement_id` based on `day`, or `month`?

I have the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./input/data.csv', sep=';')
df['connect_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['connect_start'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

How to group the month and plot the `advertisement_id.value()`?

Here is my attempt, and my computer has crash multiple times. Can anyone help.

```
df['connect_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['connect_start'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

df.groupby('connect_start)['advertisement_id']
```

Comment: So you want to plot an histogram per day or month ?

Comment: hi, eventually i want to do both. per day and month, if possible. and make a dashboard using dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close!

Once your `connect_start` column has been transformed to datetime, you can extract `month` or `day` like this:

```
df["my_date_column"].dt.day
```

Then, you can **group** the data with `groupby` as you have done.

Then, you can  **sum** per group by calling the `sum` method. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

Finally, you can **plot** it from `DataFrame.plot.bar`. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

Here is a working example:

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2019)

##############################################
# Just for example: create a random dataset  #
##############################################

number_row = 10


def random_dates(start, end, n):
    """  Generate n random dates between the interval """
    start_u = pd.to_datetime(start).value//10**9
    end_u = pd.to_datetime(end).value//10**9
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"connect_start": random_dates("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31", number_row),
                   "advertisement_id": np.random.randint(0, 10, number_row)})

print(df)
#         connect_start  advertisement_id
# 0 2019-09-08 18: 34: 48                 0
# 1 2019-11-05 06: 30: 10                 0
# 2 2019-05-03 01: 32: 15                 7
# 3 2019-01-13 06: 37: 25                 8
# 4 2019-12-04 03: 47: 36                 5
# 5 2019-11-23 14: 12: 14                 3
# 6 2019-09-09 18: 39: 50                 0
# 7 2019-10-01 08: 38: 53                 2
# 8 2019-04-05 21: 37: 19                 5
# 9 2019-04-25 04: 26: 52                 7

##############################################
#                   Process                  #
##############################################

# Convert connect_start as datetime type
df["connect_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df.connect_start, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Extract day of month, date, month in 3 new columns
df["day_in_month"] = df["connect_start"].dt.day
df["day_per_year"] = df['connect_start'].dt.date
df["month"] = df["connect_start"].dt.month

print(df)
#           connect_start  advertisement_id  day_in_month day_per_year  month
# 0 2019-09-08 18: 34: 48                 0             8   2019-09-08      9
# 1 2019-11-05 06: 30: 10                 0             5   2019-11-05     11
# 2 2019-05-03 01: 32: 15                 7             3   2019-05-03      5
# 3 2019-01-13 06: 37: 25                 8            13   2019-01-13      1
# 4 2019-12-04 03: 47: 36                 5             4   2019-12-04     12
# 5 2019-11-23 14: 12: 14                 3            23   2019-11-23     11
# 6 2019-09-09 18: 39: 50                 0             9   2019-09-09      9
# 7 2019-10-01 08: 38: 53                 2             1   2019-10-01     10
# 8 2019-04-05 21: 37: 19                 5             5   2019-04-05      4
# 9 2019-04-25 04: 26: 52                 7            25   2019-04-25      4


# Compute the number advertisement_id per group
df_day_in_month = df[["advertisement_id", "day_in_month"]].groupby(by="day_in_month").sum()
df_day_per_year = df[["advertisement_id", "day_per_year"]].groupby(by="day_per_year").sum()
df_month = df[["advertisement_id", "month"]].groupby(by="month").sum()

# Fulfill with 0 for all days off the month
df_day_in_month_all_days = df_day_in_month.reindex(np.arange(1, 32), fill_value=0)


#####################################
#               Diplay              #
#####################################
# Create figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

# Define subplots
df_day_in_month.plot.bar(ax=axes[0, 0], rot=0)
df_day_per_year.plot.bar(ax=axes[0, 1], rot=45)
df_day_in_month_all_days.plot.bar(ax=axes[1, 0], rot=0)
df_month.plot.bar(ax=axes[1, 1], rot=0)

# Prevent plot overlapping
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

If you have some matters with not full range period (depends on the size of your dataset), you can artificially add `0` values where there are no values. I dit it for the lower left plot.

Hope that help !

Comment: this is super helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: I have few questions also when you compute the number of advertisement per group.
         ```df_day_in_month = df[["advertisement_id", 
            "day_in_month"]].groupby(by="day_in_month").sum()```                                     How do you know when you use two brackets instead of one? Is it because its object inside an object?

Comment: and maybe say i have a third column which is a place where user log in to use internet. (place_name) when do i filter out ```placename = (df['place_name'] == 'Station1''``` to filter a place based on what advertisement_id shown based on the hour.

Comment: @NandaChristanto Actually `["advertisement_id", "day_in_month"]` is a **list**. There are two brakets because I select a list of columns (here 2). If you select **one** column, it useless to define it as a `list`. For the last comment, it looks to be the same by selecting the appropriates columns.